# Unboundedness of an LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

> Let $(P)$ be an LP of the form
>
> $$\min \{ c^tx\}, \text{ with } Ax \le b,x \ge 0.$$
>
> Show that if $(P)$ is unbounded then there is a vector $d$ such that $Ad=0,d \ge 0$ and $c^td<0$ holds.

I only see a slim resemblance to the Weak Duality Theorem here. Could you help me?

Comment: No it is $c^td <0$. As I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to show it like this.

Let $G = \{x| Ax \leq b, x\geq0\}$ Let $x$ be in $G$ and $Z(x)$ the possible directions to go and still be in G, i.e. $d \in Z(x) \iff x+td \in G $ for all $t \in [0, \bar{t}]$ with some maximal step length $\bar{t}(d,x) $ 
Since the problem is unbounded there must exist a d so  that $\bar{t}(d,x) = \infty$ (or else it would be bounded.) and the value of the objective function becomes smaller. d is then the direction to improve the value.

$\bar{t} = \infty $ means that $d \geq 0$ or else the resulting point won't stay in the feasible area (because of $ x\geq 0$).

Also $x+td \in G \Rightarrow A(x+td) \leq b$ or $ t(Ad) \leq b - Ax$ for all $t \in [0,\infty]$. That implies $Ad=0$.

Since d is the direction to improve the value, $ c^t x > c^t(x+td)$ or $c^td < 0$.